# How to find the most recently edited file in NSIS

Tags: winapi, installation, nsis

I have an NSIS script that pulls other installers from a local share.  Some of these update very often.  Rather than push out a new NSIS script every time, I'd like the script to look for the most recent installer matching a pattern in a certain directory.  Is there a plugin or a Windows API that I can call from NSIS to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute batch files with the !system command (at compile time)